# SSAS : Last 12 months data from cube returning NULL

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, cube, ssms-2012

I run this query in SSMS 2012

```
SELECT YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2003])ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I am getting this error

> Executing the query ... Obtained object of type:
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet Formatting. Cell set
>   consists of 1 rows and 0 columns. Done formatting. Execution complete

I want to select last twelve months from Cube and aginst that want to show some measures.

**EDIT 1:**

when I try to fire it against one of the measure it is showing `null`

```
SELECT YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2003].[8])ON 0 ,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

output is:

[image]

where i am lacking. somebody can redirect me to the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at [YTD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms146039.aspx) documentation - it expects member expression. You specified `[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2003]` - that's strange, as I suppose there is Year = 2003, not month. Anyway, if you want to get last 12 months, you should try

```
select
{
   [Measures].[Total Sales] // for example
} on 0,
{
   Descendants(
               Ancestors(
                          Tail(EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Day].members,1).Item(0),
                          [Date].[Calendar].[Year]
                        ) // end ancestors
            ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
              ) // end descendants

 }
 on 1
from [YourCube]
```

Now a bit of explanation. `Tail(EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Day].members,1).Item(0)` gives you last date existing in the cube `Calendar dimensions`. You need months, so there are two steps remaining:

- get year for this date
- get months for this year that exist in cube hierarchy

`Ancestors` here is used to get Year member (second parameter [Date].[Calendar].[Year]). Now we have moved to Year level, so we are ready to get all months using `Descendants` function, which gives all members of level related to [Year], here we specify [Month]. Please check listed functions MSDN documentation also

Comment: actually it is not an error, query just gives no result. Can you try extracting single member, like [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2003].[8], without YTD function?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070114]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the year to date using the level we have specified i.e. days:

[image]

We could then aggregate the above using a custom measure like so:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[YTDtotalTo14jan] AS 
    Aggregate(YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070114])) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[YTDtotalTo14jan] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Looks like you just picked a bad year 2003 !

To return the last 12 months I'd use the `Tail` function:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0 //<<add whatever measures you like in here
 ,Tail
  (
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
   ,12
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

p.s. this runs fine in my `SSMS`:

```
SELECT YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2003])ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is not an Error message...

> Executing the query ... Obtained object of type:
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet Formatting. Cell set
>   consists of 1 rows and 0 columns. Done formatting. Execution complete